# AJax call issue with Form authentication in MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using cookie based form authentication in my application and login in my application through ajax .when i apply Authorization tag in my web.config.my ajax function stop calling login action method in controller. my code is here.any suggestion please...

```
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**Controller ActionMethod**

```
   [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName, string Password)
    {}
```

**AJAX Method**

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Secur")',
                data: "{userName:'" + UName + "',Password:'" + UPwd + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {

                    if (msg == "Successed") {

                        window.location.href = "Home/Dashboard";}


                },
                error: function (e) {`enter code here

                    return false;
                }
            })
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question??

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Your not posting the AntiForgeryToken so remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` or pass the token

Comment: i also remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] but still not working.when i remove authorization tag from web.config.ajax call works fine.but i need to use form authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this. In the config you have:

`<deny users="?"/>`

Which means deny anonymous users. But the controller method has this attribute:

`[AllowAnonymous]`

That seems odd. Either that method is callable by anyone, or it's not; it can't be both.

EDIT:

To make things easier, removing the config setting

`<deny users="?"/>`

means anyone can access the site, since you are not using the `[Authorise]` attribute, but are using `[AllowAnonymous]`. If you do have

`<deny users="?"/>`

then you must remove `[AllowAnonymous]` and add the `[Authorise]` attribute. Let us know if it's still not working.